# Evaluation in dplyr::case_when()

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

Following an example given in the `dplyr::case_when()` documentation:

```
x <- 1:50
case_when(x %% 35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz",
          x %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
          x %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
          TRUE ~ as.character(x))
```

I expect that the number `35` will produce `"buzz"` but it produces `"fizz buzz"`

My reasoning is that `case_when()` evaluates all statements one by one regardless if a previous one is true or not (since it does evaluate `TRUE ~ as.character(x)` which is the last one) and that `35 %% 7` is obviously 0.

What am I missing?

Comment: The statements are evaluated in order, and anything that matches against the first statement will get the first result, and will not be overridden by later results.

Comment: I am still puzzled as why this last statement TRUE ~ as.character(x) is evaluated.

Comment: There are `x` values that are not divisible by 35, 5, or 7 - so there are still values left to deal with after the first 3 statements are dealt with. If you are still confused can you try to explain in more detail why you think something else should be happening?

Comment: @Marius I was confused by this TRUE ~ as.character(x) as it seems to me it apply to the whole x. I understand that this is a way to have an "other" clause.

Comment: It would apply to the whole `x` *except* where some other case wins out.  When multiple cases are true, the first one listed "wins". So when using `TRUE ~` it's important that it be listed last, or the cases listed after it will never win.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> case_when() evaluates all statements one by one regardless if a previous one is true or not (since it does evaluate TRUE ~ as.character(x) which is the last one)

This is misleading, the output of `case_when()` is based on the first statement that is true.

`TRUE ~ as.character(x)` means that if x is not divisible by 5 or 7 then then x will be returned as a string ie for x = 5, "5" will be returned.

If x is divisible by 5 or 7, `casewhen()` does not evaluate subsequent cases. "fizz" and "buzz" are *not* passed to `as.character(x)` and they do not have to be because they are already character strings.

Comment: You're right that `case_when` takes the value from the first true case, but actually subsequent cases are still evaluated, as can be seen if they have side effects.  E.g., This will return `"foo"`, but you still get the warning from the second case: `case_when(TRUE ~ "foo", TRUE ~ warning("bar"))`

Comment: Similarly, this will return `2`, but afterward `x` is `3` because it was incremented twice: `x <- 1; case_when(TRUE ~ (x <- x + 1), TRUE ~ (x <- x + 1))`.  (To be clear, I'm not recommending using side-effects like this in actual code -- it's just an example.)

Comment: @TimGoodman Thanks this is a good point and I should have known. I am often caught out by setting TRUE ~ NA, instead of the appropriate NA_[class]_, even though I received an error in cases where I thought TRUE ~ was never evalutated, I did not join the dots.